# How can I filter tag_description()?

Tags: filters, shortcode

I have a shortcode comprising:

```
$tag = get_term_by( 'slug', 'sample-tag-slug', 'item_tags' );
echo tag_description( $tag->term_id );
```

I need to do a `str_replace` on the description, for which I guess I need to `apply_filters` - but have no idea how, despite an extensive search and a very large brain-fade.

UPDATE: because of the points raised in answers and comments, I'll add the full content of the shortcode below.

```
$tag = get_term_by( 'slug', 'sample-tag_slug', 'item_tags' );
$description = tag_description( $tag->term_id );
echo str_replace(  'alt=""> ', 'alt=""><dl><dt>', $description ) . '</dt>';
$show_posts = new WP_Query(array( 'tax_query' => array(
array( 'taxonomy' => 'item_tags', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => array( 'sample-tag_slug' )
), ), 'post_type' => 'item', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'order' => 'ASC' ) ); while ($show_posts->have_posts() ): $show_posts->the_post(); echo '<dd><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></dd>' . "\n"; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();  echo '</dl><hr />';
```

What I'm trying to do is, for a cpt and custom taxonomy, show the tag description and the linked-titles of posts so-tagged. (The str_replace is to add some html tags for formatting display.)

Although I know relatively (very!) little about this, I'm keen to learn - so if there's an optimal way I'll welcome suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: shortcodes shouldn't `echo`, they should `return` a string. [See the notes in the Codex article on `add_shortcode()`.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode#Notes)

Comment: @Pat J Thanks. I'd forgotten that. The full shortcode contains more than is in my original post... and which is wrapped in 'ob_start();' and 'return ob_get_clean();'. Relatively inexperienced, I don't know whether this is a solution to potential problems of 'echo' in shortcode.

Comment: The `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` method works (because you're `echo`ing into a buffer which is then `return`ed), but IMO it's cleaner to simply do something like `$str = tag_description( $tag->term_id ); return $str;` than jump through the `ob_*()` hoops just so you can `echo` things. (Just my opinion, though; both methods work.)

Comment: Output buffering is a last resort solution. It's not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The filter is well hidden, but you can track it down from [`tag_description ($tag)`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/tag_description/), which calls [`term_description ($term=$tag, $taxonomy = 'post_tag')`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/term_description/), which in turn calls [`get_term_field ('description', $tag, 'post_tag')`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_field/). And finally you get the call [`sanitize_term_field ('description', $tag->$description, $tag->tag_id, $tag->post_tag, 'display')`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_term_field/).

Once you're in [`sanitize_term_field`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_term_field/) you see a whole lot of filters. It looks like you need the last one, which would translate to `tag_description`, but given that I'm doing the parsing from the top of my head some debugging might be necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I'm relatively inexperienced, and hence will return to your suggestion when I've learned more (and feel fresher). :-)

Comment: Or just go with Tom's solution. It's the easiest.

Comment: @cbjb Thanks. I've just added a comment to Tom's suggestion... explaining that I'm relatively inexperienced (read: 'way out of my depth'), and don't know enough to use it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a filter for `tag_description()`, but there's nothing stopping you just using `str_replace()` when you output it:

```
$tag = get_term_by( 'slug', 'sample-tag-slug', 'item_tags' );
$description = tag_description( $tag->term_id );
echo str_replace( 'search', 'replace', $description );
```

Comment: Thanks. Although that works, I'm now wondering whether wrapping the full content of the shortcode (which is more than is in my original post) in 'ob_start();' and 'return ob_get_clean();' is a solution to potential problems of 'echo' in shortcode

Comment: If you're outputting a lot of separate things, output buffering generally makes life easier. If you just wanted the filter to add HTML tags it'll be easier to just echo them on either side and use output buffering for returning the result.

Answer (score 0):

Why use `tag_description` at all, cut out the middle man and go straight to the source!

```
echo wp_kses_post( $tag->description );
```

Now you can do your `str_replace` directly, no filters necessary

Comment: Thanks. I'm relatively inexperienced, and don't know enough to use your suggestion. I'll read about wp_kses_post and try to understand.